# SQLAlchemy, postgres inherit model which have more than one primary key column

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

With `SQLAlchemy`, I want inherit a model with more than one primary keys, example:

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, create_engine, ForeignKey,
                        ForeignKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr


#engine = create_engine('sqlite:///memory')
engine = create_engine('postgres:///memory')
Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Test2(Test):
    __tablename__ = 'test2'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.id'), primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('test.id2'), primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
            UniqueConstraint(cls.id, cls.id2),
            ForeignKeyConstraint([cls.id, cls.id2], 
                                 [Test.id, Test.id2]),
        )

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {
            'inherit_condition': (cls.id == Test.id and cls.id2 == Test.id2),
        }


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The inherit work with only one primary key column, and this not really my use case. I have two String primary key column and I use the polymorphic pattern of `SQLAlchemy`. I don't write all my code, the issue is the same with or without polymorphic configuration.

This code works with `sqlite`, but not with `postgres`, the `__table_args__` is useless here, What do I miss ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I found, the foreign key constraint in the `column` must be removed

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, create_engine, 
                        ForeignKeyConstraint)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


#engine = create_engine('sqlite:///memory')
engine = create_engine('postgres:///memory')
Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Test2(Test):
    __tablename__ = 'test2'
    # No foreign key here
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        # this constraints must be the alone to Test model
        ForeignKeyConstraint([id, id2], [Test.id, Test.id2]),
    )


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```